# Apply single signon for a site running on IIS 7 over Windows Server 2008 Standard

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, windows-authentication

How do I make my Intranet site having Single Signon implemented while deployed it on IIS 7 over Windows Server 2008?

I know in IIS 6, or in Windows 7/ Windows Server 2008, I could right-click "Windows Authentication" in IIS for my site, and it would display Providers where I could select "NTLM". However, this is not the case with IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008 Standard. "Providers" option is not there entirely.

what I want is - my users should be authenticated automatically if they are accessing from within same domain, and login prompt shouldn't be appearing

Thanks

Nirman

Comment: See [this Server Fault thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/29521/iis7-basic-authentication-module-missing). It's about Basic Auth, but the steps are the same if you don't see Window Auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open IIS, click on your IIS Site.
2) Double click on Authentication Icon
3) Enable Basic Authentication  and click EDIT to set it up.

Comment: I have already, Basic and Windows Authentications enabled. And also have set domain names (and realm domain) in Basic authentication. but that still does not work.

Comment: Did you also enable anonymous user ?